# Option to import global packages into virtual environment I create?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am new to using python, so bear with me if I make any assumptions.. So I have `virtualenv` and `pip` installed in my ubuntu machine. Every time I create a virtual environment I have to remotely download and install python modules(using `pip install`) such as django already installed in the main python package.

The problem is that I am not always connected to the internet. Is there a way I can load modules existing in the main Python to every virtual environment I create? Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to install Python packages offline?

Answer (score 1):

You can `pip download` the Python packages you want to install offline and then install the `.whl` files in your `virtualenv`. Here is an example with Django and Requests:

1. Create a directory to store local Python packages:
   `mkdir local_python`
2. Change directory: `cd local_python`
3. Download Python packages to be available offline:
   `pip download django requests`
4. Install local package `.whl` files after you activate your `virtualenv`:
   `pip install Django-1.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl requests-2.16.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl`